# Javascript Match Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript

i have problem with match regular expression for search text:

```
"nama.jason".match(/\.(.*?)/g);
```

and Result

```
["."]
```

How to result `[".jason"]`

Thank's

Comment: remove the `?`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log("nama.jason".match(/\.\w*/g));
console.log("nama.jason+miraz".match(/\.[a-z]*/gi))
```

Comment: How if "nama.jason+miraz".match(/\.\w+/g); result is "[.json]"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using es2015, you can you [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

```
const str = 'name.json';

console.log(str.endsWith('.json'));
```